# Webpack 5 dev server does not reload on file changes

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm very new to webpack so please be indulgent but I can't figure out why it is not reloading the page when a modification is detected. With some old version of webpack just running webpack-dev-server was enough but with these latest versions I can't get there.

Here is my config :

```
const path = require('path')
 
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/scripts'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: [
                  ['@babel/preset-env']
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
    },
    target: ['web', 'es5'],
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
      watchContentBase: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

Here is my script :

```
"scripts": {"dev": "webpack serve --mode=development"}
```

versions I'm running :

```
"webpack": "^5.11.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

You need to update webpack-dev-server, installed version is not supported by webpack 5.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server@next
```

I also highly recommend that you familiarize yourself with [Release Note](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.0).

Be careful the update contains many **BREAKING CHANGES**!

Comment: It's not working either after making the update, and changing some stuff regarding the config( like the static thing) Probably missing something else that changed. And I mean, I used the webpack 5 doc and there is no mention about this compatibility issue but yeah I will check this thanks

Comment: webpack 5 is new and not all README.MD files are up to date, which is why I recommend reading the release note, and if you listened to my advice, you would know - "the contentBase, contentBasePublicPath, serveIndex, staticOptions, watchContentBase, watchOptions were removed in favor of the static option"

Comment: I did listen and literally mentioned  this static option change in my comment just right  above, I took care of those changes before testing again and see that it was still not working...

Comment: I have the same problem, I did install the latest and fixed all options that were mentioned in the release note and it doesn't refresh the page for me either.

Comment: Fixed the reload by following these instructions https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2758#issuecomment-710086019

Answer (score 0):

```
target: 'web',
devServer: {hot: false}
```

see [document webpack DevServer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverlivereload)